# Получение списка из ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, сериализация

Есть метод,который отправляет серверу команду, в ответ сервер отправляет список автомобилей. Метод:

```
ArrayList<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(carList);
    try {
        outputStream.writeObject("getCarList/");
       carList=(ArrayList<Car>) inputStream.readObject();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(carList);
```

Только дело в том,что только при первом использовании метод возвращает правильный список.То есть, если после первого использования кто-то внесёт изменения и ,например, добавит запись в список,а я вызову этот метод, то он всегда возвращает список,который был возвращён после первого вызова метода. В чём может быть дело?
P.S. сервер отправляет корректные значения.

Comment: Какие изменения? Где? На сервере? Или на клиенте? А они сохраняются вообще?

Comment: если вы на сервере отправляете каждый раз один и тот же объект, который изменяете, то во второй и последующие разы вместо объекта целиком отправляется "ссылка", которую клиент восстанавливает. Можете на сервере использовать `writeUnshared`.

Comment: @zRrr спасибо большое, помогли, но я сделал,чуть по-другому я просто при отправке создавал новый список, в который заносил запись из старого и отправлял уже его.